# Some problems from section 4 of Munkres

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory, axioms

I'm right now covering Section 4 of Topology by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition, and am stuck with the following problems in the exercise set after Section 4:

Problem 8(c):

Show that given $a$ with $0 < a < 1$, we have $\inf \{ a^n | n \in Z^+ \} = 0$. Hint: Let $h = (1-a)/a$, and show that $(1+h)^n \geq 1+nh$.

Now I can show that for any $h > 0$, we have $(1+h)^n \geq 1+nh$, but how do I use this hint to show what we've been asked in the problem?

Problems 9(a), (b), and (c):

How to prove these facts using only the axioms of the section and using only the preceding problems in the exercise set?

Comment: the point is that $1+h = \frac1{a}$. as $1+nh$ is unbounded and monotonically increasing with $n$ so is $\frac1{a^n}$ giving the result. re the remainder, i'd suggest you actually state here the questions you want to ask. asking people to look up the questions elsewhere is not likely to get a very enthusiastic response

Answer (score 2):

As David Holden said in the comments, if $h=\frac{1-a}a=\frac1a-1$, then $\frac1a=1+h$, and for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ you know that $\frac1{a^n}=\left(\frac1a\right)^n=(1+h)^n\ge 1+nh$ and therefore $a^n\le\frac1{1+nh}$. What happens to $\frac1{1+nh}$ as $n\to\infty$?

$9$(b) asks you to show that if $x\notin\Bbb Z$, then there is exactly one $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $n<x<n+1$; in other words, every non-integer lies between exactly one pair of successive integers. Suppose first that $x>1$. Let $A=\{n\in\Bbb Z_+:x<n\}$

By the Archimedean property $A\ne\varnothing$, and then by Theorem $4.1$ $A$ has a least element $m$; let $n=m-1$. By hypothesis $x\ne n$, so $x\ne n$. If $x<n$, then $n\in A$ with $n<m=\min A$, which is absurd, so we must have $n<x<n+1$. If $0<x<1$, there’s nothing to prove: just take $n=0$. That leaves only the case $x<0$. In that case use Exercise $2$(c) to conclude that $0<-x$; then use what we’ve just proved to conclude that there is an $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $n<-x<n+1$. Finally, use Exercise $2$(d) a couple of times to complete the proof.

$9$(c) asks you to prove that if $x-y>1$, then there is at least one $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $y<n<x$. If $x\in\Bbb Z$, what can you say about $x-1$? If $x\notin\Bbb Z$, apply $9$(b).

$9$(d) asks you to prove that if $y<x$, then there is a rational number $z$ such that $y<z<x$. HINT: If $y<x$, then $x-y>0$. Show that there is an $n\in\Bbb Z_+$ such that $nx-ny>1$ and apply $9$(c).

Comment: Thanks very much. I think 9(d) is easy once 9(c) is established. But what about 9(a)?

Comment: @Saaqib: You’re very welcome. If $\varnothing\ne A\subseteq\Bbb Z$ is bounded above, say by $m$, let $-A=\{-n:n\in A\}$. Show that $-A$ is bounded below by $-m$. Let $B=-A+m+1=\{n+m+1:n\in -A\}$, and show that $\varnothing\ne B\subseteq\Bbb Z_+$. Conclude that $B$ has a smallest element, say $b$. Now work backwards to find the smallest element of $-A$ in terms of $B$, and use that to find the largest element of $A$.

Comment: So nice of you for such an encouraging response.